# Why do browsers allow some global variables in the strict mode?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, multiple-browsers, strict-mode

I cannot figure it out, why do some browsers allow the next code, and others do not:

```
'use strict';
(function() {
  Number = 1;
  toString = 1;
  valueOf = 1;
})();
console.log(Number);
console.log(toString);
console.log(valueOf);
```

- Chrome 52 on Windows throws on toString and valueOf, but allows Number.
- Chrome 49 on Linux throws on valueOf, and allows others.
- Firefox 47 allows all.
- IE 11 allows Number.
- Opera allows Number.

At first, when I spotted this in Chrome, I thought, this is because of these "variables" had been already defined as properties of the global object. But `window.hasOwnProperty('toString')` returns false, as well as for 'valueOf'. So I have no idea.

Could anyone explain this, please?

*I'm asking because I need to test in unit tests, that global variables were not modified and this behavior makes it hard, because I do not know what behavior is the correct one so I could rely on it and not to find one day that it was fixed.*

Comment: `window.hasOwnProperty('toString')` tests if `window` has an *own* property, however, this is (prototypal) inherited from `Object`.

Comment: @fdomig, I know this, that is why I thought that `use strict` forbids everything, which was not declared/assigned as an own property of the global object